# Are there MPPT solar chargers that can also do coulomb counting/current measuring or is that a separate function? (for NiMH)

Tags: current-measurement, solar-charge-controller, mppt

Are there any MPPT solar chargers that can also do coulomb counting, or do you need a separate fuel gauge IC for that? I have been looking for a while and there is no proof that an IC even exists that can do both functions. Is coulomb counting/current measuring only on ICs that are meant as a fuel gauge?

Comment: Why would you need coulumb counting on NiMH?  That's more of a lithium thing.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I think I need it because I want to be able to estimate SoC (to know when to recharge) and capacity (to know when to replace the battery with a new one).  It also seems to be the most accurate method of doing this over time that I have heard of.

Comment: This question is extremely close to being of the product recommendation type, which are explicitly off-topic because of their nature (an answer of "no that doesn't exist" today could turn into a "yes" tomorrow). But the answer to "Are there any...?" is yes, and the answer to "Is coulomb counting...only on...a fuel gauge?" is no. For example the LTC4015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any MPPT solar chargers that can also do coulomb counting

No.

That's the job of the BMS, not the job of the charger. Charging and battery management are two distinct functions, which are handled by two distinct devices:

- Charger: It limits the voltage and current to level appropriate for the **battery**. It has no knowledge of state of charge, and no knowledge of the voltage of each cell in the battery. It's a **regulator**, not a switch.
- BMS: monitors the voltage of each and every **cell**. If necessary, it interrupts the current. It measures the current in and out of the battery and from that it may evaluate the SoC. It's a **switch**, not a regulator.

Do not conflate charger and BMS: they are different.

> Is coulomb counting/current measuring only on ICs that are meant as a fuel gauge?

Yes.